# Certain links to document library show no documents or folder

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library

I've got an issue adding folders (previously only filtered on meta-data) to a document library. When I follow a link to the library, or in the summary views (e.g. when embedded in another page) the library shows "There are no items to show in the view of the "Document Library" document library. To add a new item, click "New" or "Upload"."

If I press any of the red links here it shows things like this:

[image]

But there is a bunch of folders with files in the library. Either looking at windows explorer, or clicking the lower document Library link highlighted in red here and everything is fine! That's exactly what I need to see.

I've ended up having to distribute a link for this, and people are having to bookmark it etc and there's a lot of confusion as things dissapear when there should be folders there,

[image]

I had a look at the links and I noticed that the one that shows folders uses `RootFolder=`.

Empty Link:

```
http://something.net/sites/SiteName/Document%20Library/Forms/AllItems.aspx
```

Populated Link:

```
http://something.net/sites/SiteName/Document%20Library/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2Fsites%2FSiteName%2Meeting%2FDocument%20Library&
```

Is there any way I can specify it to just look in the root folder by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Managed to fix this by deleting and re-creating the library. It seemed that there's an important root folder "/1" that I'd deleted.